.NET for Android Project Cannot Access Resources From Referenced Project
I have a Solution containing 2 Projects, one containing Resources & Classs, and the other is a .NET for Android app (which references the first). The first Project compiles with no problem, but the second seems unable to find Resources located in the first Project. The second Project is able to access the Classs & method(s) with no problem, just not the Resources. Both Projects are able to access their own Resources with no problem, so the Resources are obviously being generated. Here are some of the errors generated by the second Project:
APT2260 resource style/BasicEditTextStyle (aka com.companyname.ScorePad:style/BasicEditTextStyle) not found.    ScorePad    C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\35.0.7\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets
CS0117  'ResourceConstant.Color' does not contain a definition for 'Transparent'    ScorePad    D:\NetForAndroid_Experimental\ScorePad\PointsAdapter.cs
APT2260 resource color/Gray (aka com.companyname.ScorePad:color/Gray) not found.    ScorePad    D:\NetForAndroid_Experimental\ScorePad\Resources\values\styles.xml
APT2062 failed linking references.  ScorePad    C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\35.0.7\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets

Note that the Project listed in all of these errors is "ScorePad" (the project that is an app), even though the Resources are located in the other Project. I don't know if it is related or not, but I also receive the following error:
CS8700  Multiple analyzer config files cannot be in the same directory ('D:\NetForAndroidAppExtras').   NetForAndroidAppExtras  D:\NetForAndroidAppExtras\CSC

Note that the Project listed in this error is "NetForAndroidAppExtras" (the project containing the Resources). Could this be related to the problem? Why is my app Project able to find the Classs, but not the Resources? Thanks!

I believe I finally found the answer. After searching based on some of the stuff from the Output tab rather than the Error List tab, I found the following page:
Migrate from FxCop to source analysis (.NET) - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Learn
As stated in this page, you need to set RunCodeAnalysis to false as follows (in the *.csproj file):
<RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
This fixed everything for me, and hopefully it will for you too!
